# How to get login username and insert into another table in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am a blog page where i will be inserting blogs from admin panel.while inserting blogs into database i need to insert admin username as well into the database for the blogs.How to get the admin username and insert into blogs table.

Controller:

```
function addblogs()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_title','Blog Title');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Blog Description');        
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {       

    $data['mainpage']='blogs';
    $data['mode']='add';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this -> blogs_model -> insertblogs();
        $this->flash->success('<h2>blogs Added Successfully!</h2>');
        redirect('blogs');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function insertblogs()
{
    $username = $_SESSION['name'];

    $title=$this->input->post('blog_title');
    $result = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);

    $data=array(

    'blog_title'=>$this->input->post('blog_title'),
    'blogtitle'=>$result,
    'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
    'user'=>$username
    );
                $this->db->insert('blogs',$data);           
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
        $form_attributes  = array('name'=>'adds', 'id'=>'adds', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
        echo form_open('blogs/addblogs',$form_attributes);
    ?>

    <div class="element">
        <label for="blogtitle"><font color ="black">Blog Title</font></label>
        <input class="text err" type="text" name="blog_title" id="blog_title" value="<?php echo set_value('blog_title');?>"/>               
    </div>  
       <div class="element">
        <label for="description"><font color ="black">Blog Description</font></label>
        <textarea name="description" id="myArea1" rows="4" cols="173"></textarea>
    </div> <br/>        
    <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Login Controller:

```
if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){
        $data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
        $data['records']=$this->career_model->get_jobs_list();
        $data['mode'] = "all";
        $data['mainpage'] = "career";
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
```

Login Model:

```
<?php
class login_model extends MY_Model
{
 function login_user($user_name = '', $password=''){

    $userdetails = array(
    'user_name' => $user_name,
    'password' => md5($password),
    );
    $this->db->where($userdetails);
    $query = $this->db->get('login_details');
    if($query->num_rows()):
        $user = $query->result();
        $sess_arry = array(
            'user_id' => $user[0]->user_id,
            'name' => $user[0]->name
        );          
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', $sess_arry);        //add admin details to session  
        return true;
    else:
        return false; 
    endif;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the name in `$username = $_SESSION['name'];` ?

Comment: getting error as undefined variable _session

Comment: can you show your login code where you was set session.

Comment: @RazibAlMamun i have updated my login controller

Comment: I have submitted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can some change your model in `insertblogs()` method like that :

```
$this->load->library('session');
$logged_data = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');

$user_id = $logged_data['user_id'];
$user_name = $logged_data['name'];

$username = $user_name;//$_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the logged-in user by:

```
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

now you can use this `$username` to insert it in database or you can perform some other functionality.

Comment: Inserting as 0 not getting username

Comment: Put `print_r($username);` to see what it contains ?

Comment: Nothing it is displaying inserting directly into the database

Comment: Not displaying anything getting blank page

Comment: Means username is not available in session, show all sessions and check what it contains?

Comment: function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('session');
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->load->model('blogs_model');
   if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){
    $this->data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
   }
   else{
    redirect('welcome');
   }
  }

Comment: for checking the user is logged in or not i used this functionality

Comment: Can you explain it little i am not getting that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142820/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-ashalatha).